# Or operator/ random number

Tags: c#, if-statement, random, or-operator

I'm having trouble with the or operator and random number generator. I'm wanting the random number generator to pull a number between 1 and h with h been chosen by a user and stored as 1,6,11 and 16 then I wish the if statement to look at the random number and decide if it is to do what I have programmed or go and perform the else statement. At the moment it only seems to perform the if statement and never the else (the second else, the first one works fine). The code I have is

```
        Random random = new Random();
        int ran = random.Next(1, h);
        if (s1 == 0 & s2 == 0 & s3 == 1)
        {
            s3 = s3 - 1;
            cover0.Visible = true;
            p1slable.Visible = true;
            p2slable.Visible = true;
            playagain.Visible = true;
            score.Visible = true;
            p1score.Visible = true;
            p2score.Visible = true;
            c = c + 1;
            p2slable.Text = "" + c.ToString();
            labelscore2.Visible = true;
            winner2.Visible = true;
            hintcover.Visible = true;
            e1.Visible = false;
            e2.Visible = false;
            e3.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (s1 == 0 & s2 == 0 & s3 == 2)
            {
                if (ran == 1 || ran == 3 || ran == 4 || ran == 5 || ran == 9 || ran == 10 || ran == 15)
                {
                    s3 = s3 - 2;
                    cover0.Visible = true;
                    p1slable.Visible = true;
                    p2slable.Visible = true;
                    playagain.Visible = true;
                    score.Visible = true;
                    p1score.Visible = true;
                    p2score.Visible = true;
                    c = c + 1;
                    p2slable.Text = "" + c.ToString();
                    labelscore2.Visible = true;
                    winner2.Visible = true;
                    hintcover.Visible = true;
                    e1.Visible = false;
                    e2.Visible = false;
                    e3.Visible = false;
                }
                else { s3 = s3 - 1; }
```

and i am using c# 2015

Comment: have you tried setting `ran` to 6 (or some other value that will move it to the `else` statement) yet?

Comment: your problem is a bit hard to understand. Could you please indicate clearly which if is always true? And did you try to run  it in the debugger to check what kind of values you get and if they correspond to what you expect.

Comment: you are missing a bit of code there. Does the `if` inside the first `else` have itself an `else` clause? Or are there simply to closing curly braces missing in your code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code is not complete. I'll assume that whats missing in your snippet are simply two closing curly braces.

With that in mind, lets refactor your code so this mess of *ifs* and *elses* is a little easier to understand.

First of all, why are you checking `s1` and `s2` twice? You can check once and then check `s3`.

Also, you want to use the `switch` statement when branching on numerous constant values. Its more readable and it removes the need of infinite and ugly *orings* like your `ran` check.

```
 var random = new Random();
 var ran = random.Next(1, h);

 if (s1 == 0 && s2 == 0)
 {
     if (s3 == 1) //case handled: s1 = 0, s2 = 0, s3 = 1
     {
         s3 = s3 - 1;
         //... etc.
     }
     else if (s3 == 2) //case handled: s1 = 0, s2 = 0, s3 = 2
     {
         switch (ran) //all cases handled
         {
             case 1:
             case 3:
             case 4:
             case 5:
             case 9:
             case 10:
             case 15:
                 s3 = s3 - 2;
                 //... etc.
                 break;
             default:
                 s3 = s3 - 1;
                 break               
         }
     }       
 } // s1 != 0 or s2 != 0 will jump here
```

Ok, now that we have it written like this, its a little easier to reason about what cases you are handling and which one you aren't.

You are only handling cases where `s1` and `s2` are equal to zero and `s3` equals either `1` or `2`. Thats it. Any other value of `s1`, `s2` or `s3` will simply ignore your whole code because it will not find a matching `if` or `else` clause. Is this what your really want?

Answer (score 0):

ran the debugger and it works fine now have no clue why it was not working before and what the debugger does or did. thank you for your time for helping me. (had no clue there was a debugger only been using the program for a few weeks making a game,(nim))